# Hibernate lazy initialization - failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting the following error whenever I try to retrieve data from my Users table, I've searched a web a lot trying to find out what could be wrong but couldn't find anything so can someone please help me by telling me what I am missing / I have wrong here?

Error:

> ERROR: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role: com.domain.crm.domain.Role.users, no
>   session or session was closed
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: com.domain.crm.domain.Role.users, no session or
>   session was closed

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COM_USER")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="USER_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="USER_NAME",nullable=false,length=25,unique=true)
private String userName;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID",nullable=false)
private Role role;
}
```

Role Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COM_ROLE")
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ROLE_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="ROLE",nullable=false,unique=false)
private Integer Role;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="role")
private Set<User> users=new HashSet<User>();
}
```

User DAO class Method being invoked to collect all users:

```
public List<User> getUsers(Long page, Long pageSize) {
    Long start = (page-1)*pageSize;     
    return sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User u ").setFirstResult(start.intValue()).setMaxResults(pageSize.intValue()).list();
}
```

User Service class method:

```
@Transactional
public List<User> getUsers(Long page, Long pageSize) {
    return userdao.getUsers(page, pageSize);
}
```

Controller class calling the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/list-user-data")
@ResponseBody
public UserListData listUserData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {

    UserListData listData = new UserListData();

    String page = request.getParameter("page");
    Long pageLong = Long.parseLong(page);
    Long pageSize = (long)15;

    List<User> searchResults = iuserservice.getUsers(pageLong, pageSize);

    if( searchResults != null ){
        List<List<Object>> aaData = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
        List<Object> listItem = null;

        for( User u : searchResults ){
            listItem = new ArrayList<Object>();
            listItem.add(u.getLastName());
            listItem.add(u.getFirstName());
            listItem.add(u.getUserName());
            listItem.add(u.getEmail());
            listItem.add(u.getRole());

            aaData.add(listItem);
        }
        listData.setAaData(aaData);
    }



    int totalCount = iuserservice.getAllUsersCount().intValue();

    System.out.println("Number of records in DB:  "+totalCount);
    listData.setiTotalRecords(totalCount);

    return listData;
}
```

Finally here is my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <!-- Mysql -->  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>           
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <!-- Commons DBCP -->   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>           
</dependencies>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: The error says it all. You load the object from the database then close the session. You object is then in a detached state. You then try and access a lazy collection. You need to either extend the scope of the session - open session in view is a good pattern. Or you can eagerly load the collection.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Please take a moment to check the User class, I already Eagerly load the collection

Comment: @BoristheSpider I also didn't close the session in anyway, the error appear while I am in the middle of the controller method, even before it finish process. Thanks

Comment: @MChan: no, you don't eagerly load the users. OneToMany associations are lazy by default. And yes, the session is closed as soon as the transaction ends, i.e. just after the transactional `UserService.getUsers()` method returns.

Comment: You should do your processing in the service method. And should return `UserListData` from the service method!

Comment: @JBNizet I am sorry but I am confused here, in the User class I am loading the Roles eagerly by @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER), do I have to load the Users eager from the Role class as well? I am quite confused now

Comment: @MChan: When I go to your SO profile, I see that you're from Hong Kong. You thus have a ManyToOne association with Hong Kong. But, by seeing your profile, I can't know all the SO users from Hong Kong. It's the same here: you load a user and you know its role. But that doesn't mean that you know all the users having this role.

Comment: @JBNizet Hmmm, based on your reply I guess my problem is more of entities relationship problem. In other words what I have now is that Each ROLE can have 1 to n USERS, then from the USER class I eagerly loaded ROLES, while based on your reply I should do the opposite, meaning I should Eagerly load Users from ROLE class...am I getting this correct?

Comment: I don't know what you should do. All I say is that either your code, or, presumably, the library that serializes what you return from your MVC method to XML or JSON, tries to access the users of the roles, and that since this association has not been loaded, it fails. You probably need to configure this library to not serialize non-loaded associations, or not try to serializee roles but transform the into DTOs that "cut" the association.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I post the example here. The basic idea would be just to have 3 database tables where 2 are for entities `User` and `Role`, and last one as mapping table, say `user_role`. In user table we store user details, in role table we store role id and name and in our mapping table we map the user to role. I copy from my one own project. The BaseEntity that my classes extend is just a mapped superclass that has general fields for every entity such as id, created/modified date etc.

User entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_t")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> role = new HashSet<Role>();

    // getters & setters
}
```

Role entity

```
@Entity(name = "role_t")
public class Role extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false)
    private String roleName;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

Note that `ManyToMany` by default uses eagerly fetch type so we don't need to set it. Now when I would query for my `User` entity from my service. The `role` collection would not get fetched. If I need to get roles that belong to that user then I need to manually fetch them with the query. I use Spring Data JPA repository and the query for example would look like that for a single result.

UserRepository class

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.role WHERE u.userName = (:userName)")
    public User findByUserNameAndFetchRoles(@Param("userName") String userName);

    @Query("FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.role")
    public List<User> getAllUsersAndFetchRoles(); // **query that you would use!**
}
```

And then in your `UserService` layer you would use that repository/DAO query. For me using the eagerly fetch on the roles is necessary, because every time I would want to query for userlist, I don't don't need to get the roles, because in my real project the roles also have a set of permissions and it's just not worth to query for stuff you don't need.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `@OneToMany` associations are lazy by default and by the time you call `getUsers()` the session is already closed in your service method. 
One way to solve it is by eagerly loading child records. **But be careful, as this might cause you load too many data which will slow it down and kill memory.** For example, in your `Role` entity, if you set it to eagerly load `Users`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="role", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<User> users=new HashSet<User>();
}
```

Whenever you load a `Role`, Hibernate will load all its child `Users`.

One way to handle your case is do all the work on the service inside `@Transactional` method which should ensure session is still open(It's better to have service methods `@Transactional` instead of DAOs)

```
@Transactional
public UserListData getUserListData(Long page, Long pageSize) {
    List<User> searchResults = userdao.getUsers(page, pageSize);
    UserListData listData = new UserListData();
    if( searchResults != null ){
       List<List<Object>> aaData = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
       List<Object> listItem = null;

        for( User u : searchResults ){
            listItem = new ArrayList<Object>();
            listItem.add(u.getLastName());
            listItem.add(u.getFirstName());
            listItem.add(u.getUserName());
            listItem.add(u.getEmail());
            listItem.add(u.getRole());

            aaData.add(listItem);
        }
        listData.setAaData(aaData);
    }
 return listData;
}
```

Comment: I've moved all the code in the service class as you have just recommended but I still get the same error, also I have set fetchtype to eager

Comment: This will not work. If you call getRole() on user entity, then the role collection still isn't initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere (not shown in your code above) you are accessing some method of the `users` collection field in a `Role` entity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load `Roles` collection from the same transaction with eager fetch type. To work around that you need to manually initialize the Roles collection or do `fetch join` on your query. This should fix it for you.

```
public List<User> getUsers(Long page, Long pageSize) {
    Long start = (page-1)*pageSize;     
    return sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.role ").setFirstResult(start.intValue()).setMaxResults(pageSize.intValue()).list();
}
```

Also I would recommend having `ManyToMany` relationship between `User` and `Roles` and use the mapping table. Use the below and remove user set from role entity. It's redundant to duplicate role records on the roles table.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> role = new HashSet<Role>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how come many to many between Users and Roles, a User can have only ONE role, but a role can belong to MANY users, so it is one to many relationship, unless I am missing something here so can you please explain why many to many?

Comment: Role based access control best practice is not to assign role to user, but assign user to role. You have to think more widely about your database design. If you ever plan to expand it then you are stuck with your solution. With ManyToMany you create roles and you map the user with role through a mapping table. This allows you to expand your solution if you ever plan to add permission/authority based authentication.

Comment: As far as I've read ROLES are pretty static, meaning that I can't dynamically build new ROLE_ so all ROLES must be defined in code first (Example: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CLIENT...etc) then an ID is assigned to each ROLE_ which is saved in ROLE table. If I made a many to many relationship between Users and Roles this means a User can have multiple ROLES in the same time so far am I following you correctly? OK, now in term of expandability, I am already limited with the static ROLES so it is not as expandable...makes sense?

Comment: No, the roles are not static, you have to read up on what the roles actually in Spring Security are. It's a wide misconception on their part and rather confusing. The role you assign wherever in your application is just a name that has to start with ROLE_ prefix, which actually is not a role, but in fact an authority. Under expanding I mean an example like this: http://slackspace.de/articles/roles-permissions-with-spring-security-3/

Comment: Same problem after using JOIN FETCH, I still get error ERROR: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.domain.crm.domain.Role.users, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.domain.crm.domain.Role.users, no session or session was closed

Comment: Can you debug your code, does the query actually fetch the roles with it, see the sql print and what gets stored in the `searchResults` list.

Comment: OK, I tried debugging, what is really silly here is that the SQL goes smoothly the result set is returned with the Role id, but it just crashes with the out of session exception. Ironically, I am calling the DAO methods responsible for the query from inside the same service method, so I am really confused why it is still giving me out of session exception!!

Comment: Now that's really weird, at first it showed the Role id returned correctly now it shows something like com.domain.crm.domain.Role@4a0fd899 in role id field after finishing the query. it is getting really confusing each time

Comment: You should really re-design this structure a little. Currently you are not using role as collection, instead it's just a field and the roles table stores some id-s that won't tell you anything and may confuse others. If you want to go with your solution then rather store the actual role names to the database and map an id for each user. Then again this design is something I don't like. Hardcoding any values to your logic code is very bad. There are good design patterns around the web that may make your goals faster.

Comment: I've tried to follow up the design you referenced in http://slackspace.de but it was a bit confusing for me as I am not used to XML definitions. Unfortunately I learned Hibernate, Spring all annotation based, so XML confuses me a bit. So I was wondering if you know any tutorial / website offering example on best security practices using Spring security / annotation based? Thanks in advance